# When exporting jasper report in pdf is not showing marathi character

Tags: jasper-reports

When exporting jasper report in pdf is not showing marathi character(Using unicode) which is passed to the parameter.

```
  JRExporter ex=new JRPdfExporter();
  ex.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING,"UTF-8");
  ex.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
  ex.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,"E:/DATA/"+fileNewNameF);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved using

```
JRGraphics2DExporter exporter = new JRGraphics2DExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRGraphics2DExporterParameter.GRAPHICS_2D, grx);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.PAGE_INDEX, new Integer(i));
exporter.exportReport();
```